# Как atomikos понимает по каким ресурсам делать транзакцию

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, transaction, jta

Как atomikos понимает по каким ресурсам делать транзакцию??
Перерыл кучу мануалов. Везде просто создается jta менеджер спринговый и все.
Все объявления самих ресурсов, там DataSource или ConnectionFactory никак не привязаны к менеджеру транзакций.
Даже в чистом мануале, без спринга, создается просто менеджер транзакций и все.
И как это по умолчанию в спринг буте устроено?
Там можно по умолчанию объявить только 1 ресурс подключения к базе и 1 к jms??
А если захочу больше, то как быть? Просто описывать ресурсы и они сами подтянуться?